# How to convert a formatted local time to epoch?

Tags: r

I have a local time like `"2013-08-27 10:01:22"`, how do I convert it to epoch time?

basically I need the opposite of `as.POSIXct`, I searched on google and surprisingly didn't find any.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `as.integer` to get seconds since epoch began...

```
x <- as.POSIXct( Sys.time() )
#[1] "2013-08-27 12:37:17 BST"

class(x)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

as.integer( x )
#[1] 1377603437
```

Using a vector of strings called `times`:

```
times
#[1] "2013-08-27 12:39:32" "2013-08-27 12:39:33" "2013-08-27 12:39:34"
#[4] "2013-08-27 12:39:35" "2013-08-27 12:39:36" "2013-08-27 12:39:37"
#[7] "2013-08-27 12:39:38" "2013-08-27 12:39:39" "2013-08-27 12:39:40"
#[10] "2013-08-27 12:39:41"

as.integer( as.POSIXct( times ) )
#[1] 1377603609 1377603610 1377603611 1377603612 1377603613 1377603614
#[7] 1377603615 1377603616 1377603617 1377603618
```

Without the timezone in the strings you will probably have to specify the `tz` argument to `as.POSIXct`, e.g. `as.integer( as.POSIXct( times ) , tz = "BST" )` for British Summertime.

Comment: Should you have sub-second resolution you need to use `as.numeric` instead of `as.integer` as sub-second are stored as decimal of a second

Comment: `POSIXct` represents time to the nearest second. That's a different date/time format.

Comment: Thanks both of you, it would be nice if it can work with format like "2013-08-27 10:01:22.123456", but I don't really need the sub second bit at the moment.

Comment: @swang what is your input data like? A vector of strings?

Comment: @swang As I said for sub-millis `x <- as.POSIXct('2012-06-01 12:32:12.123')` `as.numeric(x)` will give you `1338546732.123` (carefull with `options(digits)` it needs to be big enough)

Comment: @statquant: I tried it but it didn't work:
> x<-as.POSIXct("2013-08-27 10:01:22:123456")
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1377594082

Comment: the separator of micros is `.` not `:` and you need `options(digits=16)`

Comment: tried that too:
> x<-as.POSIXct("2013-08-27 10:01:22.123456")
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1377594082

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer truncates time to the whole second. `POSIXct` actually provides sub-second resolution, though. As mentioned in the comments by “statquant”, you can use `as.numeric` to obtain the exact epoch:

```
result = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))
```

Beware that with the default options for digit display in R this will *look like* it has no digits behind the decimal point:

```
> result
[1] 1480599768
```

However, these are simply truncated in the display. To make them visible, use:

```
> dput(result)
1480599767.58447
```

… or set `options('digits')` to a higher value.

Answer (score 2):

we can also use

```
unclass(Sys.time())
```